# How to find the energy bands of a kagome lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, tight-binding

I've been trying to solve the tight binding for a kagome lattice. The thing is that I find a cubic equation and have no idea on how to solve it. There's this article though (https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05455), and on page 3 he states the solutions are $t\left(1\pm\sqrt{2\sum_i\cos k_i+3}\right)$ and $2t$. Working on it I came up to the same matrix as the one written by the author, but I can't see how to find these eigenvalues. I've tried to put it on Maple but it gives me a solution that takes up to 5 lines. So how do I find these solutions?

Comment: You can solve for the characteristic polynomial. Instead of using the general Cardan formula (I suspect that’s what Maple gave you), notice the “obvious” solution $E=2t$ and factor it you revert to second degree polynomial.